# In Outer Dark, is the Tinker a good man?

Tags: character-analysis, cormac-mccarthy, outer-dark

He finds the infant and seems to want to take care of it. On the other hand, when we later encounter the child, it shows signs of grievous injury that it seems must have occurred (or probably) while in the Tinker's custody.

But the bottom line, the old man saves the child from certain death. His behavior towards the mother reflects I think his disgust (misplaced) with someone who had abandoned her own child. The injuries could have been an accident, perhaps reflective of the Tinker not being very good at dealing with a young child.

The worst case would be that he had specifically taken the child to abuse him, but given that he goes to his sister for help with the infant, that seems unlikely.